# Is there a fast way to assign the same values to elements with the same names in a vector?

Tags: r

For example, the vector

```
xx = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 5, 8, 3, 2,4)
```

the name of each element in xx is:

```
 names(xx) = c('a', 'b','a','c', 'b', 'b', 'c','b', 'c', 'c')
```

Is there a fast way to re-assign the value of each element in xx to the maximum value of elements with the same names? For example, the maximum value of elements with the name 'a' is 3, so I will assign 3 to all the elements with the name 'a'.

Please note I do not want to sort the names of xx. So, is there a fast way to achieve this goal without using looping?

Comment: `ave(xx, names(xx), FUN = max)`

Comment: Thank you so much! Really amazing!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ave` solution is the best. However here is an alternative using `dplyr`:

```
keys = c('a', 'b','a','c', 'b', 'b', 'c','b', 'c', 'c')
k<-data.frame(keys , xx) 
k %>% group_by(keys) %>% mutate(xx=max(xx))

Source: local data frame [10 x 2]
Groups: keys [3]

     keys    xx
   <fctr> <dbl>
1       a     3
2       b     5
3       a     3
4       c     8
5       b     5
6       b     5
7       c     8
8       b     5
9       c     8
10      c     8
```

Comment: No need for the detour via another variable, you can modify existing variables: `k %>% group_by(keys) %>% mutate(xx = max(xx))`. — Also, please improve the formatting of your code by using spaces around binary operators.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You are right. Edited per suggestions.